# Angular 5 proper way to customize node_module .js File

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules

I have searched Google and Stackoverflow. I feel like my question would be common, so perhaps I am not using the proper search terms.

In my Angular 5 Project, I have added pdfmake by running `npm i --save pdfmake`. This has added the expected .js files to */node_modules/pdfmake/dist*. One of these files is called *vfs_fonts.js* which I have updated following instructions on the pdfmake website so that I can add my own fonts.

So, being new to Angular 5 and node, my question is this: should I simply overwrite the *vfs_fonts.js* file which exists in */node_modules/pdfmake/dist*? This seems wrong to me since if I were to install my project on another machine, `npm install` would not get my customization.

What is the proper way for me to override this .js file in my node_modules? Do I need to pull pdfmake out of my node_modules to create a custom package which I include in my .angula-cli.js? I hesitate to do this because I would rather not lose all the benefits of npm.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you edit the code in node_modules but whenever you will do **npm install** it will restore back to old changes.

Best option is you can **fork** the package repository. You can install items directly from GitHub using NPM, and this method would let you integrate future changes into your custom version from the original source.

And then you can use this:

```
npm install https://github.com/<username>/<repository>/master
```

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: In my particular case, I was able to get around the issue because I could tell pdfmake to use my own vfs-fonts.js (pdfMake.vfs = my_vfs) from another location in my project. I am checking this answer as correct because I ended up using this solution for another project I also customize in my app.